# Get index of array and store inside a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a function `getStoreAreaData()`. It will loop through out my list of array which is

```
//list of array
storeAreaData = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];


function getStoreAreaData(){
    //storeareadata mag hohold ng array ng storeAreaData
    holdStoreAreaData = storeAreaData;

    //now holdlengtharray holds the array of holdstoreareadata
    var holdLengthArray = holdStoreAreaData.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < holdLengthArray; i++) {
            //this holdgetStoreAreaData now holds all of the data of the array;
            holdGetStoreAreaData = holdStoreAreaData[i];
            document.write(holdGetStoreaAreaData);
            //create a variable that will hold the array

    }
}
```

Inside of the `for` loop, I stored the `holdStoreAreaData` inside `holdGetStoreAreaData`. My problem is that I want to put it inside a variable that holds their indexes, or is there other way to access the indexes straight through the `holdGetStoreAreaData`?

E.g. something like

```
holdGetStoreAreaData[0] = 1;
holdGetStoreAreaData[1] = 2;
holdGetStoreAreaData[2] = 3;
holdGetStoreAreaData[3] = 4;
```

?

Comment: Isn't the variable `holdStoreAreaData` exactly what you want?

Comment: Do you want to *clone* the array? It's not clear to me why you are doing what you are doing.

Comment: What is the objective of `document.write(holdGetStoreaAreaData)`?

Comment: I don't see why you would need to have another array containing the indexes.

Comment: Amir - Yes it is one of the things that I want,but it shows list of the arrays, I want to (if possible) to get their indexes directly without using holdGetStoreAreaData[0] ?

Comment: @SendhilkumarAlalasundaram just for checking if the array is already in my variable

Comment: @StigCoder04 because I need those indexes to search for my json file. so I need to get their indexes and store it in a variable and with that variable I will use it for searching.

Comment: @FelixKling I dont think that I have to clone the array since I just want to get their indexes and store it inside a variable

Comment: I think it's unclear what exactly you mean by "get their indexes". Indexes of what?

Comment: @BryanRance, but isn't your index right there in holdStoreAreaData? Or create a jagged array in which the first element is the data and the second  is the index.

Comment: @FelixKling I have a search function, where when I get the index of the array from  holdGetStoreAreaData , I will store it inside a variable then use that variable  for my search function, thats why I have to get their indexes

Comment: @StigCoder04 jagged array? sounds like thats what I needed, but still I havent found it, I will take a quick research about it

Comment: @BryanRance or 2D array, because in this case,  the number of elements in each element of the array are consistent.

Comment: *"get the index of the array from holdGetStoreAreaData"* `holdStoreAreaData` is an array of numbers. Are you saying that every number in that array is an index of some other array (not shown in your example)? It's still not clear to me which "indexes" you are talking about. You really have to provide a better explanation and/or example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append to a list:

```
holdGetStoreAreaData = []
for (var i = 0; i < holdLengthArray; i++) {
        holdGetStoreAreaData.push(holdStoreAreaData[i]);
}
```

A better way to clone the array is

```
holdGetStoreAreaData = holdStoreAreaData.slice(0);
```

See the [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

[image: here is the image of tabular array]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div>
<input type="button" onClick="getStoreAreaData()" value="Click">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var storeAreaData = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

function getStoreAreaData(){

var holdGetStoreAreaData=[];

for (var i = 0; i < storeAreaData.length; i++) 
{
holdGetStoreAreaData[i]=storeAreaData[i];
console.log("holdGetStoreAreaData["+i+"]:",holdGetStoreAreaData[i]);
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```